# Delete row in html if all cells blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm generating a table based on some external data. Every row does not have data in the columns I'm returning. I'd like to delete the row that have **all** cells empty. I have found some code to delete the row if one cell is empty, but one empty cell is allowed. I'd like to delete the first and third rows.

I've tried this, but it deletes all rows:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>123</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td>456</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

$("td").each(function() {
  if (this.innerText === '') {
    this.closest('tr').remove();
 }    
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply modify your script to iterate over `tr` elements instead of `td`.

If the text content of a `tr` row is blank, that means all of its cells are blank, as well. Here's a working demo:

```js
$("tr").each(function() {
  if (!$(this).text().trim()) {
    this.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>456</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @mcadamsjustin Did you click "Run code snippet"? It deletes the first and third row, just as you asked.

Comment: @Mukyuu That's what OP had originally.

Comment: I did run the snippet in Firefox, didn't work. I then ran it in Chrome and it worked. That seems odd

Comment: @mcadamsjustin Thanks for that - I've modified the code to work in Firefox, as well. Adding the `trim` functionality to ensure no whitespace was in the string comparison fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use each of the tr elements like this. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
$('tr').filter(
    function(){
        return $(this).find('td').length == $(this).find('td:empty').length;
    }).hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1g7hqkvb/

Comment: this works, but @JonUleis answered first, thanks for the help

Comment: @mcadamsjustin: Yeah, thank you for voting my friend :d